# pass variables to post method with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Hello I am trying to pass 2 variables from select menu to ajax POST code.

here is the select menu:

```
<?php echo "<select name='status' id='$id' idc='$idc'>" ?>
```

here I am not sure if this is alowed to be declared like this. I mean put variables inside the select menu.

where the variables are declared before like that:

```
$idc = $row['userID'];
```

So this is whee I am sendind the variables to the POST method

```
selectstatus = $("select[name=status]").val();  
var id = $(this).attr('$id');
var idc = $(this).attr('$idc');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "selectbackend.php",
    data: {"selectstatus": selectstatus, "id": id, "idc": idc},
```

some kind it is not passing anything at all. where might be the problem ?

Comment: The top line of code is valid and will output a dynamic select object in your HTML. To check that for correctness, view your page source. What is being submitted to "selectbackend.php"? Can you log it somewhere or echo it back to your originating page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the attribute names '$id' and '$idc', but your attributes are called 'id' and 'idc', so the `id` and `idc` variables will be undefined.

This should do the trick:

```
selectstatus = $("select[name=status]").val();  
var id = $(this).attr('id'); // id, not $id
var idc = $(this).attr('idc'); // idc, not $idc
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "selectbackend.php",
    data: {"selectstatus": selectstatus, "id": id, "idc": idc },
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sel = $("select[name='status']");  
var id = sel.attr('id');
var idc = sel.attr('idc');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "selectbackend.php",
    data: {"selectstatus": sel.val(), "id": id, "idc": idc}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using html5 you can define custom attributes starting with `data-`

```
<?php echo "<select name='status' id='$id' data-idc='$idc'>" ?>
```

While on client side you can get the values as below

```
    var  selectstatus = $("select[name=status] option:selected").val();  
            var id = $("select[name=status]").attr('id');
            var idc =$("select[name=status]").attr('data-idc');
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "selectbackend.php",
            data: {"selectstatus": selectstatus, "id": id, "idc": idc
           }
           });
```

Suggestion : May be need to make ajax request on some event like `onchange`